# Double Curtain Reveal Effect of Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, footer

I'd like to build a footer, which reveals when the bottom of page is reached, kinda like this:
https://www.thecssninja.com/css/reveal-effect

So far so good, I have that.
What I want to add now is an additional information within the footer, which gets revealed, when the other part of the footer is shown completely.

One could say, that I have two fixed footer parts. After the whole page is scrolled it will reveal the first part. And then this first part must somehow change from fixed to normal positioning allowing it to scroll up further to reveal a second footer part (fixed) underneath.

Does somebody know any examples (can include JS stuff) or does anyone have a trick for this?

Thanks for all the help.

Cheers